# Why employer want to fire an employee?

Tags: professionalism, management, communication, work-environment, employer-relations

I'm clueless regarding a private job to understand thier managing behaviour. I want to understand this situation when an project has finished and they start to cut-down. I want to understand these professional issues.

I've 4 questions :

1. Why employer want to fire an employee?
2. Is/are any ego in management system?
3. How must performe to be nice employee?
4. Why employer want to break his commitment for perticular(or any) employee?

> Can you explain please? I want to understand these professional issues.

Comment: Right now it is unclear what you are asking. It sounds like you are asking "Why would anyone ever fire someone?", which is extremely broad and not a good fit for the Q&A format of this website. Please take a look at our [Help Center](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for tips on how to ask good questions.

Comment: You do realize that some of us answering may be giving answers that are specific to our region, right? Like my answers apply in Canada and the US but may not be as accurate for other locations as I haven't worked there.

Comment: If these are serious questions and it's not all just a disgruntled rant then they should be split off to separate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might come across as rude, but here are my answers to your 4 questions:

```
1) Why employer want to fire an employee?
```

The employee is costing the company more money than they are making the company.

```
2) Is/are any ego in management system?
```

Always. But firings are not necessarily related to the ego.

```
3) How must perform to be nice employee?
```

Quality deliverables provided to the company in short time-frames that make money for the company. Also, if it is an English speaking company, only speak English in the workplace and do it well.

```
4) Why employer want to break his commitment for particular(or any) employee?
```

That depends on the particular employee, doesn't it? But again, the bottom line is that the employee is eating up more money in manpower hours than they are generating sellable deliverables.

Answer (score 2):

> Why employer want to fire an employee?

Lots of reasons. In your example, it's likely to save money.

> Is/are any ego in management system?

Often, yes.

> How must performe to be nice employee?

I'm not clear what you are asking with this one.

> Why employer want to break his commitment for perticular(or any) employee?

Note that today, in many industries, there's very little commitment on the employer's part. At the end of the day, an employee is an asset that can make or cost money for the company.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why employer want to fire an employee?

Perhaps the company needs to save money and thus employees have to be "laid off" which is still a form of termination. There could also be issues where the employer doesn't like the employee's performance, personality or other factors and decide that their services are no longer needed.

> 2. Is/are any ego in management system?

Yes, there can be ego in management though I'd question how deep does it go and how well can one measure it.

> 3. How must performe to be nice employee?

Even if an employee is nice, there can still be issues. I've had places that terminated my working there as I didn't meet expectations. I've also had companies that imploded and thus I was let go rather than fired though the result is similar in that I had to find a new employer to supply me with income.

> 4. Why employer want to break his commitment for perticular(or any) employee?

If the employee messes up badly enough, the employer may well fire someone to limit liability for an easy answer. Secondly, if the employee can't do the work then they may be fired for not meeting expectations. Thirdly, if management decides to lay off staff then some people may be let go as part of how business works. Have you ever had an employer that couldn't pay you? I have. There can also be personality conflicts where someone may be fired for being difficult to manage. There can also be questions of being a fit and so someone may be fired for those reasons, which has happened to me during my first few months at a company.

Beware that the company has expectations of what an employee has to do. If that isn't met then the question is what can be done and are there legal issues as people with disabilities may well get some accommodations in the workplace.